# AngularJS SVG rendering order using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I'm having rendering order issues when trying to order or reverse a list of `<g>` elements using `ng-repeat` directive. Here's a plunkr to reproduce it: http://plnkr.co/edit/f2pgSq?p=preview

I'd like to use intensively Angular's `orderBy` and `filter`. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `ng-attr-y="{{y + (item.id - 1) * (h + 6)}}"` of `<rect ng-repeat...>`.

Change it to

```
ng-attr-y="{{y + $parent.$index * (h + 6)}}"
```

What you want is to use the `$index` of the outer repeater instead of the `id` since the `id`s will get reversed.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/J0Swjj?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Oops, I should have seen that. Thank you!